# F# async: parent/child cancellation?

Tags: apache-kafka, f#, confluent-platform, f#-async

So here we go: given a `Confluent.Kafka` `IConsumer<>`, it wraps it into a dedicated `async` CE and consumes as long as cancellation hasn't been requested. This piece of code is also defends itself against the `OperationCancelledException` and runs `finally` block to ensure graceful termination of consumer.

```
let private consumeUntiCancelled callback (consumer: IConsumer<'key, 'value>) =
    async {
            let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
            try
                try
                    while not ct.IsCancellationRequested do 
                        let consumeResult = consumer.Consume(ct)
                        if not consumeResult.IsPartitionEOF then do! (callback consumeResult) 
                with
                | :? OperationCanceledException -> return ()
            finally
                consumer.Close()
                consumer.Dispose()
    }
```

**Question #1:** is this code correct or am I abusing the `async`?

So far so good. In my app I have to deal with lots of consumers that **must** die altogether. So, assuming that `consumers: seq<Async<unit>>` represents them, the following code is what I came up with:

```
async {
        for consumer in consumers do 
            do! (Async.StartChild consumer |> Async.Ignore).
    }
```

I expect this code to chain childs to the parent's cancellation context, and once it is cancelled, childs gonna be cancelled as well.

**Question #2:** is my finally block guaranteed to be ran even though child got cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two observations about your code:

- Your use of `Async.StartChild` is correct - all child computations will inherit the same cancellation token and they will all get cancelled when the main token is cancelled.
- The async workflow can be cancelled after you call `consumer.Consume(ct)` and before you call `callback`. I'm not sure what this means for your specific problem, but if it removes some data from a queue, the data could be lost before it is processed. If that's an issue, then I think you'll need to make `callback` non-asynchronous, or invoke it differently.
- In your `consumeUntilCancelled` function, you do not explicity need to check while not if `ct.IsCancellationRequested` is true. The async workflow does this automatically in every `do!` or `let!`, so you can replace this with just a `while` loop.

Here is a minimal stand-alone demo:

```
let consume s = async {
  try
    while true do 
      do! Async.Sleep 1000
      printfn "%s did work" s
  finally
    printfn "%s finalized" s }

let work = 
  async {
    for c in ["A"; "B"; "C"; "D"] do  
      do! Async.StartChild (consume c) |> Async.Ignore }
```

Now we create the computation with a cancellation token:

```
// Run this in F# interactive
let ct = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(work, ct.Token)

// Run this sometime later
ct.Cancel()
```

Once you call `ct.Cancel`, all the `finally` blocks will be called and all the loops will stop.